# How would you explain the A natural in bar 11?

Tags: harmony

How would you explain the A natural in bar 11?
How would you explain that the phrase ends in bar 11 and not bar 12?

[image: Score of *Jesus från Nasaret går här fram*]

Answer (score 10):

This melody could be harmonised in several ways.  But there's a strong implication that from bar 8 the music moves towards G minor, reaching a cadence in that key at bar 14. Hence the A♮ and F♯.  G minor chord has two notes in common with E♭ major, which makes the modulation connected, if somewhat novel.  (E♭ major to G MAJOR would be a 'Chromatic mediant', another common harmonic shift.)

Here's a version (I imagine the standard version?) that harmonises in this way.

Music doesn't have to fall into 4-bar phrases.  This piece has a 4, 3, 4, 3, 4 phrase structure.  Nice, isn't it!  Musical traditionalists might be tempted to add an extra bar (or perhaps a fermata) at bars 7 and 14 in order to even it out into 'correct' 4-bar phrases. (More so 100 years ago than now, perhaps.) I'm glad this version doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that 4 - 3  cadence.  Makes for a nice "unfinished" feeling internal to the piece.

Comment: How is G minor connected to Eb major?

Comment: Eb major and G minor triads have two notes in common.  That's enough to make them sound connected.  But you can modulate anywhere!  There's no requirement to sound as if nothing's changed.

Comment: "There's no requirement to sound as if nothing's changed": indeed, it's rather the point of modulation to sound like something has changed, isn't it?